# csv file group by col1 and display max value of col2

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

Following is the csv file which i need to get the data from

```
hour, count
-----------

00,23

00,34

01,34

01,45

02,30

02,50
```

i would want to write a power-shell script where i get the following output

```
hour,max(count) for unique hours
--------------------------------

00,34

01,45

02,50
```

i tried to group using the group-object and measure-object, but i am not able to get the above desired result

```
Import-Csv d:\test\serviceyrs.csv | Measure-Object -Property count -Minimum -Maximum
```

gives me the total maximum and minimum count, but not what i want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maximum you'll get like this:

```
Import-Csv -Delimiter ',' -Path C:\sample\csv01.csv | 
    Group-Object -Property hour | 
    Select-Object -Property Name,@{N='Sum';E={($_.Group | Measure-Object -Property count -Maximum).Maximum }}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#file which needs to be inputted
$revisedcsv="path\of\the\filename\plus_name"_revised.csv"
#filename which would have the results

    $finalfilename="path\of\the\filename\plus_name+"_final.csv"

    Import-Csv $revisedcsv|group hour |select @{n='MaxCount';e={($_.group|measure count -Maximum).maximum}}| export-csv $finalfilename -notype
```